# Atom XML feed private gallery for Visual Studio Updates

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, feed, visual-studio-extensions

I've created a private gallery for Visual Studio, using a C# Projet to generate the Atom.xml. The download works perfectly but if i update the version of the vsix project, and the atom.xml visual studio doesn't show update.

the Atom.xml updated :

```
<1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<title type="text" />
<id>uuid:bcecded5-97c8-4d24-96f1-7d9e16652433;id=1</id>
<updated>2016-04-08T00:00:00+02:00</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>e2dea93f-86f3-45ce-b7be-290e21066050</id>
    <title type="text">ItemTemplatesGenerator</title>
    <summary type="text">It's a class generator to create structure of redondant classes.</summary>
    <published>2016-02-26T16:06:22.1655958+01:00</published>
    <updated>2016-04-08T16:34:01.4822941+02:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>NameCompany</name>
    </author>
    <category term="Files Generation" />
    <content type="application/octet-stream" src="D:\Galerie_VS\ItemTemplatesProject\ItemTemplatesProject.vsix" />
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
        <id>e2dea93f-86f3-45ce-b7be-290e21066050</id>
        <Version>1.3</Version>
        <References />
        <Rating xsi:nil="true" />
        <RatingCount xsi:nil="true" />
        <DownloadCount xsi:nil="true" />
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I've checked and the id of entry and vsix correspond with the real id of the vsix project.
We have the version 1.3 in the xml
[Visual Studio doesn't show updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31R3a.png)
Any idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: What the version of the application? Can you add a picture of the Extensions and Updates window? I want to see your extension in:1.  'installed', 2. Online (in your gallery) and 3. Updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have in my `atom.xml` this comment to remind me what I need to update:

```
  <!-- 
  When deploying change
    <updated> under <feed>
    <updated> under <entry>
    <Version> under <Vsix> == be sure to change the version in the source.extension.manifest file in the project
  -->
```

Comment: I put up to date all these fields, but it doesn't work. VS doesn't show any update

Comment: i use the same updated value in both tags, maybe that's an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I put same value in both tags too :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text" />
  <id>uuid:bcecded5-97c8-4d24-96f1-7d9e16652433;id=1</id>
  <updated>2016-06-21T00:00:00+02:00</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>e2dea93f-86f3-45ce-b7be-290e21066050</id>
    <title type="text">ItemTemplatesGenerator</title>
    <summary type="text">It's a class generator to create structure of redondant classes. Use to create classes faster.</summary>
    <published>1601-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</published>
    <updated>2016-06-21T00:00:00+02:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Compagny name</name>
    </author>
    <category term="Files Generation" />
    <content type="application/octet-stream" src=".\ItemTemplatesProject\ItemTemplatesProject.vsix" />
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
        <id>e2dea93f-86f3-45ce-b7be-290e21066050</id>
        <Version>1.2</Version>
        <References />
        <Rating xsi:nil="true" />
        <RatingCount xsi:nil="true" />
        <DownloadCount xsi:nil="true" />
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
 </feed>
```

but it doesn't works.
Second point :  Visual studio shows the download button and not the update button, but the extension is already installed.
[Screenshot Online galery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6lhT.png)